# Simple-Dialog module not working for non-admin users

Tags: forms, javascript

actually i am showing a custom form in dialog, it seems correct when admin is logged in but when other user (some other role) logged in, it shows blank screen. On console i found "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined".

Comment: Are using a Drupal module/Jquery plugin? Show some code on how you're loading content, required js for dialog.

Comment: Hi Navnet!  You seem to have 7 open questions, perhaps you could revisit them and see if any of the answers can be accepted to improve your acceptance rate.

Comment: @Mathankumar I used simple-dialog module and I m loading dynamic custom form in dialog.